# Nodejs websocket communication with external system

Tags: node.js, websocket, ipc

I'm new to nodejs and I'm trying to solve communication issue with external system.

There is a gateway to external system which can handle websocket requests on port 5000. In the example below, when you request homepage, the nodejs opens websocket connection, then on websocket open event it sends request and waits for response which is used for the HTTP response.

Do you know how to open websocket to external system only once and handle requests based on request id?

```
var ws = require('ws');
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var webSocket = new ws('ws://localhost:5000/');
    async.series([
        function (callback) {
            webSocket.on('open', function () {
                webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({query:'data query', requestid: uuid.v4()}));
                callback(null, 'data query');
            });            
        },
        function (callback) {
            webSocket.on('message', function (data, flags) {
                callback(null, data);
            })
        }
    ], function (err, results) {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
        res.send(results[1]);
        webSocket.terminate();
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Listening at %s', port)
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just open the web socket upon either server startup or the first page request and then store that socket in a variable outside the specific request.  You could then use that socket for any future requests.  If you are going to potentially run multiple requests over the same websocket from multiple page requests at the same time, then you will have to be able to differentiate which websocket response belongs with which request.

Comment: Or you could maintain N websockets in a cache and just fetch one from the cache when a request comes in and then put it back in the cache when the request is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hints. I ended with the following solution which does what I expect:

```
var ws = require('ws');
var express = require('express');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var requests = {};

app = express();

var webSocket = new ws('ws://localhost:5000/');
webSocket.on('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected!');
});            

webSocket.on('message', function (data, flags) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.requestId);
    var res = requests[json.requestId];
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
    res.send(json.data);
    delete requests[json.requestId];
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var rid = uuid.v4();
    requests[rid] = res;
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({query:'data query', requestId: rid}));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Listening at %s', port)
});
```